# Unable to set value of member variable in a service in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is my service code snippet:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserDataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  tableData = <SampleDataStructure[]>[]; // SampleDataStructure is the interface

  url: string =
    'https://some_sample_data.json'; //dummy url

  getTableData(): SampleDataStructure[] {
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((data) => {
      for (let user in data) {
        let userData = <SampleDataStructure>{};

        //setting required fields as per SampleDataStructure interface
        userData.S_No = +data[user]['s.no'];
        userData.country = data[user]['country'];
        userData.location = data[user]['location'];
        userData.num_backers = +data[user]['num.backers'];
        userData.end_time = data[user]['end.time'];
        
        this.tableData.push(userData);
        //console.log(this.tableData); // *shows data here in tableData as expected
      }
    });

    //console.log(this.tableData); //**shows empty array here
    return this.tableData;
  }
}
```

I'm expecting *tableData* to be populated with required data. Its instead showing me empty array (at line marked with comment **).
Though its showing expected data at line marked with comment *

I know I'm doing some very silly mistake, can someone please help me on this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your subscription return is probably slower so the code jumps to concluding return statement while the data is still not returned from sub, and thus returns nothing, while the this.tableData gets its expected value inside the sub as soon as the sub returns. So, move return statement inside the sub, not outside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subscription is working asynchronously. That means that the url is called and the program don't wait until it finish (`http.get(this.url)`). So the `return this.tableData;` is executed after the `http.get` is executed, but anytime before or after the `get` finish to fetch the data.

That's why the `console.log(this.tableData);` alwways shows data, and the `return this.tableData;` can return nothing or data.

The best is that getTableData return the observable like this signature:

```
public getTableData(): Observable<SampleDataStructure[]> {
   return this.http.get(this.url).pipe(map(data) => {
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it solved my problem.